# Different types of MOM (Message-Oriented Middleware)

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, spring-integration, activemq-classic, amqp

I am new to the MOM world and started learning different type of messaging frameworks,

Can someone pls explain me following?

1. JMS vs Active MQ vs Rabbit MQ
2. Spring AMQP vs Spring Integration
3. Spring AMQP with Rabbit MQ vs Spring Integration with Rabbit MQ

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

1. JMS vs Active MQ vs Rabbit MQ  : JMS provides [specifications](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jms-2_0-fr-eval-spec/JMS20.pdf?AuthParam=1498820597_9446837449d24bfa4335e14b0afad3e7) and using these specifications Apache, IBM and other vendors create their own JMS brokers. Apache provides JMS brokers like ActiveMQ and Artemis, likewise IBM have IBM MQ.